# How to Move a File in jEdit

Tags: java, file-management, jedit

In jEdit, I have a file that I want moved to another directory? I do not see an easy way to do this. Does anybody know how? I already tried looking for a plugin, but to no avail.

Comment: JEdit is a text editor and not necessarily the best tool for moving files around. Seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you actually want to achieve? (why does it have to be using jedit?)

Comment: If you are editing some project and want to move a file somewhere else, then it is probably save as to new location, close original, delete original on file system using whatever file system explorer thingy your OS provides. Is that your question?

Comment: @jakub_d I know that there are better ways to move a file, if that is what I am solely trying to do. But my main task is working with source code files through and my editor of choice is JEdit.I know there are better options like Sublime, Netbeans, but right now I'm using JEdit. I am fairly new to JEdit, and I was wondering if anyone more advanced can help.

Comment: @jakub_d Yes, that is my question and that seems to work. I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rename...` option on a file can actually also move it around. Not super convenient as you have to type or copy in the path, but at least it works. So to move the file one directory up you could rename it to `../thefile.txt`. If folders you want to move to do not exist, jEdit automatically creates them for you.